# React Native Navigation, open universal link from within own app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) for React Native. I have successfully configured it to handle universal link, which is something like this

```
// linking.ts
import { APP_ID } from '@env';

const config = {
    screens: {
        LoginScreen: 'authorize',
        RegisterScreen: 'register',
        CustomerStack: {
            screens: {
                OrderDetailScreen: 'customer/order/:orderId',
            },
        },
    },
};

const linking = {
    prefixes: [`${APP_ID}://app/`, 'https://example.com/app/'],
    config,
};

export default linking;
```

```
// App.tsx

import linking from './linking'

const App = () => {
   return (
      <NavigationContainer linking={linking}> <MyApp /> </NavigationContainer>
   )
}
```

When I press a link in the browser such as `https://example.com/app/customer/order/1234`, then it successfully opens my app's order page.

### Problem

I want to be able to open the url such as `https://example.com/app/customer/order/1234` **indside my app** and have it open the order page. I have tried

```
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://example.com/app/customer/order/1234')} />
```

but (testing on IOS) it switch to the web browser first to open the link, and then open my app.

Is it possible to open the order page directly inside my app without switching to the browser first.

**Note:** I am trying to implement an in-app notification history page, each notification item has the link saved in the database, and when the user clicks on the item I want to navigate the user to the page as configured in `linking.ts`. I know it is possible to parse the link and use `navigation.navigate()` instead, but that means I will have 2 places for the linking configuration. I think it would be great if I can reuse the existing logic provided by React Navigation.

Comment: For that app-specific links, you can convert from Universal links `https://` to deep link `yourapp://` then iOS treat them as the deep links by default

Comment: Why are you trying to `Linking.openUrl()` instead of just `navigation.navigate()`?

Comment: @MichelFloyd, thank you for taking a look at this. The reason is I want to reuse the linking configuration. `navigation.navigate()` doesn't understand the configuration. Currently I have to write another set of configurations to parse different cases of the urls and call `navigation.navigate()` for each case, which  basically is a duplication of the linking configuration with different syntax.

Comment: Yes it is somewhat duplicative but the linking configuration and the navigator serve different purposes. The navigator also deals with the *stack*, push and pop. The linking configuration in general will be simpler because it only has to deal with universal links. Jumping out to the browser and then back in to navigate is a pretty unique approach.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @asinkxcoswt

Comment: @chamara sad to say, but no, currently I parse the url and call `navigation.navigate()` manually.

Answer (score 2):

In React Navigation, you can use the [useLinkTo](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-link-to) hook. This hook allows you to navigate inside the application using a path.

This will allow you to use the following option:

```
const linkTo = useLinkTo();

return (
   <Button onPress={() => linkTo('/customer/order/1234')} />
);
```

If using a URL is mandatory, then you can use [extractPathFromURL](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/native/src/extractPathFromURL.tsx), an internal React Navigation function, to remove the prefix.

```
import extractPathFromURL from '@react-navigation/native/src/extractPathFromURL';
import linking from './linking'

// ...

const linkTo = useLinkTo();

return (
   <Button onPress={() => {
     const path = extractPathFromURL(linking.prefixes, 'https://example.com/app/customer/order/1234');
     const pathWithSlash = path.startsWith('/') ? path : '/' + path;
     linkTo(pathWithSlash);
   } />
);
```

`extractPathFromURL` is not part of the official API and may be removed in future versions. For reliability, you can create a duplicate of this function in the project.